# Uniform convergence of a series of nonnegative functions $\sum f_n$, given that $\sum f_n=\sum g_n$ and $\sum g_n$ converges uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Assume $f_n,g_n : [0,1] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} $ are continuous, $f_n\geq 0$ for $n \geq 1$ and for all $x \in [0,1]$ both series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f_n(x),\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}g_n(x)$ are convergent as well as $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}g_n(x)$.

Show that if $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}g_n(x)$ uniformly convergent so is $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f_n(x)$.

I feel it should be obvious, but I look at the definition of series uniform convergence and can't think of anything constructive.

Comment: The only thing the uniform convergence of $\sum g_n$ is needed for is the continuity of the limit function. Forget about $g_n$, and prove that $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly under the condition that $$S(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$$ is a continuous function (plus your conditions on the $f_n$ of course). Ulisses Dini may help.

Comment: So $f_n$ is decreasing (at least for all $n \geq n_0$), since otherwise the series wouldn't converge and $S(x)$ is continuous as you pointed out. Using Dini's theorem  we conclude $f_n$ is uniformly convergent. Is that ok?

Comment: The $f_n$ need not be decreasing. But the sequence $$S_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x)$$ is monotonic. And $S_n$ as well as its limit are continuous. Now call Dini.

Comment: And this is not the same as to say $f_n$ is decreasing? I must think about it. Thank you.

Comment: No, the sequence $S_n$ being monotonic(ally nondecreasing) means that for all $x$ and $n$ you have $S_{n+1}(x) \geqslant S_n(x)$ - and that is equivalent to $f_{n+1} \geqslant 0$. The $f_n$ (and the $S_n$) need not be monotonic as functions of $x$ for fixed $n$. And we can have $f_{n+1}(x) > f_n(x)$ (for some fixed $x$) for infinitely many $n$. All that is no problem, the only thing that matters (except for the continuity) is that $S_{n+1}(x)$ is never farther away from $S(x)$ than $S_n(x)$ is.

Comment: Ok I think I got this. $f_n$ needs to be bounded, but not monotonic. However partial sums have to decrease/increase because of the definition of convergent series,

Comment: Ok I may not had this as I thought :P

Comment: In the proof of Dini's theorem, what is the decisive argument?

Comment: I've seen proof by contradiction, so the contradiction of sequence of functions being not uniformly convergent was decisive... I guess.

Comment: Proof by contradiction? Hmm, can't really imagine that. The proof I'm thinking about is: for all $n$ (and $\varepsilon > 0$), the set $U_n(\varepsilon) = \{ x : \lvert S(x) - S_n(x)\rvert < \varepsilon\}$ is open (by continuity), $U_n(\varepsilon) \subset U_{n+1}(\varepsilon)$ (by monotonicity), and $\bigcup U_n(\varepsilon) = [0,1]$ (by pointwise convergence); since $[0,1]$ is compact, $\{ U_n(\varepsilon) : n \in\mathbb{N}\}$ has a finite subcover, by nestedness $U_n(\varepsilon) = [0,1]$ for all $n\geqslant n_0$. The crucial point is that $U_n\subset U_{n+1}$, which follows by monotonicity.

Comment: Wow, I've never seen topological proof, it's more... elegant. Cool. I could show you my (meaning the one I've been shown) proof, but first would've to translate it into english which could take some time so...

Comment: Anyway, I have all I need, thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>From comments by [Daniel Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/782546/series-uniformly-convergent#comment1625173_782546)</sup>

The only thing the uniform convergence of $\sum g_n$ is needed for is the continuity of the limit function. Forget about $g_n$, and prove that $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly under the condition that $$S(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$$ is a continuous function (plus your conditions on the $f_n$ of course). [Dini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini's_theorem) may help.

Proof of the theorem: for all $n$ (and $\varepsilon > 0$), the set $U_n(\varepsilon) = \{ x : \lvert S(x) - S_n(x)\rvert < \varepsilon\}$ is open (by continuity), $U_n(\varepsilon) \subset U_{n+1}(\varepsilon)$ (by monotonicity), and $\bigcup U_n(\varepsilon) = [0,1]$ (by pointwise convergence); since $[0,1]$ is compact, $\{ U_n(\varepsilon) : n \in\mathbb{N}\}$ has a finite subcover, by nestedness $U_n(\varepsilon) = [0,1]$ for all $n\geqslant n_0$. The crucial point is that $U_n\subset U_{n+1}$, which follows by monotonicity.